# Solana: Can't make createAccount work, createAccountWithSeed works

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-transaction-instruction

I am currently trying to learn on writing programs for Solana and interacting with those.

I am using the [example-helloworld](https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld) code. In order to interact with the helloworld program, the nodejs code creates an account with seed:

```js
const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.createAccountWithSeed({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        basePubkey: payer.publicKey,
        seed: GREETING_SEED,
        newAccountPubkey: greetedPubkey,
        lamports,
        space: GREETING_SIZE,
        programId,
    })
)
tx = client.send_transaction(transaction, payer)
```

My understanding is, that it creates a data account, owned by the program with the `programId`. Not sure why with seed yet.

I tried to replace this piece of code with the following:

```js
const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: greetedPubkey,
        lamports,
        space: GREETING_SIZE,
        programId,
    })
)
tx = client.send_transaction(transaction, payer)
```

but it is not working. Once the transaction is send, I get the following error:

```
{'code': -32602, 'message': 'invalid transaction: Transaction failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly'}
```

Anyone who can explain the difference and what I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating an account with `createAccount`, you must provide a signature from that new account. So in your case, `greetedPubkey` must be a `Keypair`, just like `payer`.  You can do:

```
const greeted = Keypair.generate();
const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: greeted.publicKey,
        lamports,
        space: GREETING_SIZE,
        programId,
    })
);
tx = client.send_transaction(transaction, payer, greeted);
```

`createAccountWithSeed` is special because it derives a new address from the base, meaning that you don't need to sign with the new address, only with the base address.